# Know from which device the Linux kernel booted

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot

How can I know from which device the Linux kernel booted?

Comment: The kernel does not know from where it was loaded. It could for example be loaded from the network. The kernel only knows the root filesystem. All the data the kernel needs before mounting root is loaded into memory before the kernel starts.

Answer (score 0):

```
mount
```

Unless that command specifies a device for /boot then you can assume that it's on /.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I need.
I'm creating a live system and I need the information directly from the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, something like that http://lkml.org/lkml/2003/12/19/139 can satisfy me.
But a simplier way will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```